# ChartKick throwing error "PG::GroupingError: ERROR:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chartkick

I've recently migrated my database from sqlite3 to postgreSQL for a rails app I've been working on. On one of my pages, I'm rendering a graph using "ChartKick". Prior to switching to postgreSQL my table and graph were functioning fine. Now the page fails and I get an error:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "stats.created_at" must appear in the >GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I've used the Google and tried troubleshooting it a bit but cannot get my graph to function properly.

> "<%= line_chart @stats.group(:date).sum(:weight) %>"
>
> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "stats.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: ..."."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY "stats"."date" ORDER BY created_at...
>                                                                ^
>   : SELECT  SUM("stats"."weight") AS sum_weight, "stats"."date" AS stats_date FROM "stats" WHERE "stats"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY "stats"."date" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3

EDIT
Heres what I have in my controler to query the data:

> # GET /stats.json
>     def index
>       @stats = current_user.stats.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 5 ).order('created_at DESC')
>     end

I'm also using the Ruby Gem "Paginate" for my table.

Comment: It's a PostgreSQL error, not a ChartKick error (that's why it says `PG::GroupingError::ERROR`). Perhaps it would help to show the query code.

Comment: It's probably coming from this line `@stats.group(:date).sum(:weight)`. What's the stats table look like? Is `date` the name of that database column not `created_at`?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Postgres wasn't able to group the data because my code did not specify what data to get. by adding "current_user" to my ChartKick code, it was able to SELECT and render the data fine.

*would fail*

> "<%= line_chart @stats.group(:date).sum(:weight) %>"<

*Works!*

> "<%= line_chart **current_user**.stats.group(:date).sum(:weight), discrete: true %>"